# Separar valores de una columna en dos columnas según el valor de otra columna

Tags: sql

Quisiera saber si es posible en un SELECT de dos tablas diferentes, puedo hacer que la consulta que me muestre, me de los datos de una determinada columna en dos columnas diferentes según el valor de otra columna.

Un saludo

El diseño es este:

```
       SELECT        dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Item No_] AS [Cód. Producto], dbo.[base Euro$Item].Description AS Descripción, dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Sales Code] AS Tarifa, 
                             dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Unit of Measure Code] AS [Unidad Medida], dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Starting Date] AS [Fecha Inicial], dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Ending Date] AS [Fecha Final], 
                             dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Unit Price] AS [Precio Venta], dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Precio coste] AS [Precio de coste], dbo.[base$Sales Price].[_ Bº bruto] AS [% Margen], 
                            dbo.[base$Sales Price].[_ Comisión interno] AS [% Comisión Interno], dbo.[base$Sales Price].[_ Comisión externo] AS [% Comisión Externo]
      FROM         dbo.[base$Item] INNER JOIN
                            dbo.[base$Sales Price] ON dbo.[base$Item].No_ = dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Item No_]
      WHERE       (dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Precio Vigente] = 1) AND (dbo.[base$Sales Price].[Sales Code] = N'NMP')
```

Y este el resultado:

```
Cód. Producto Descripción Tarifa Unidad Medida Fecha Inicial Fecha Final Precio Venta Precio de coste % Margen % Comisión Interno % Comisión Externo 
20004 Alambre rojo NMP CAJA 06/07/2019 0:00 ############## 1,19 1 14,5 0,6 2 
20004 Alambre rojo NMP UNIDAD 06/07/2019 0:00 ############## 1,38 1 38 0,6 2 
20005 Alambre azul NMP CAJA 06/07/2019 0:00 ############## 1,539 1,35 14 0,6 2 
20005 Alambre azul NMP UNIDAD 06/07/2019 0:00 ############## 1,701 1,35 26 0,6 2 
20020 Alambre amarillo NMP CAJA 30/11/2019 0:00 ############## 2,714 2,36 15 0,6 2 
20030 Alambre negro NMP CAJA 04/01/2016 0:00 ############## 2,99 2,59 16 0,6 2 
20030 Alambre negro NMP UNIDAD 04/01/2016 0:00 ############## 3,108 2,59 20 0,6 2 
20034 Alambre lila NMP CAJA 04/07/2020 0:00 ############## 0,91 0,93 25 0,6 2 
20035 Alambre verde NMP CAJA 04/07/2020 0:00 ############## 1,75 1,59 13,3 0,6 2 
20035 Alambre verde NMP UNIDAD 04/07/2020 0:00 ############## 1,89 1,59 18 0,6 2 
20039 Alambre naranja NMP CAJA 04/07/2020 0:00 ############## 12,93 12,55 30 0,6 2 
20039 Alambre naranja NMP UNIDAD 04/07/2020 0:00 ############## 13,75 12,55 30 0,6 2
```

Yo quisiera que para cada Cód.Producto y dependiendo del valor de Unidad Medida (CAJA o UNIDAD) saliera una sola fila con una columna para Precio Venta CAJA y otra columna para Precio Venta UNIDAD. En el caso de que CAJA o UNIDAD no exista el valor que muestre en la columna sea 0.

Esto sería lo que quiero:

```
Cód. Producto Descripción Tarifa Fecha Inicial Fecha Final Precio Venta CAJA Precio Venta UNIDAD Precio de coste % Margen % Comisión Interno % Comisión Externo 
020004 Alambre rojo NMP 06/07/2019 0:00 ############## 1,19 1,38 1 14,5 0,6 2 
020005 Alambre azul NMP 06/07/2019 0:00 ############## 1,539 1,701 1,35 14 0,6 2 
020020 Alambre amarillo NMP 30/11/2019 0:00 ############## 2,714 0 2,36 15 0,6 2 
020030 Alambre negro NMP 04/01/2016 0:00 ############## 2,99 3,108 2,59 16 0,6 2 
020034 Alambre lila NMP 04/07/2020 0:00 ############## 0,91 0 0,93 25 0,6 2 
020035 Alambre verde NMP 04/07/2020 0:00 ############## 1,75 1,89 1,59 13,3 0,6 2 
020039 Alambre naranja NMP 04/07/2020 0:00 ############## 12,93 13,75 12,55 30 0,6 2
```

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: La respuesta depende de la base de datos que estes usando... y no aclaraste cual es...

Comment: Esta pregunta ya la realizaste unas horas antes [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/411266/146637), por favor elimina una de las dos

Comment: @Israel-ICM reportala como duplicada la proxima vez.. no tiene que eliminar alguna, tiene que no repetir la pregunta...

Comment: @gbianchi, intente reportarla como duplicada pero no me permite porque me dice que no tiene respuestas. De todas formas la reporte pero como **se necesita intervención de un moderador**

Comment: @Israel-ICM perfecto.. no te preocupes ya me ocupe..

Comment: Lo siento, pido disculpas, hice la pregunta como invitado y después al registrarme la repetí.